# When will SQL SERVER's "SET ROWCOUNT" stop affecting INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE operations?

Tags: sql-server, deprecated, rowcount

I was looking for ways to systematically limit a query return. So I found the "SET ROWCOUNT" clause, but in Microsoft's documentation it already says that it will be deprecated in a future release:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15

Even though in `SET ROWCOUNT` own documentation, it says that it will not affect {`INSERT` | `UPDATE` | `DELETE`} operations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

With all this context, my question is: will SQL Server's `SET ROWCOUNT` feature stop affecting `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations in a future release?

If so, is there any information on when that will happen? I haven't found that information in the documentation clearly.

Comment: Will it: who knows? They've been threatening the same with statement termination (semi-colons) for years. What's wrong with `TOP` as the docs suggest?

Comment: `text`, `ntext` and `image` have been deprecated since 2005; they're still in SQL Server 2019 (and people still keep on foolishly using them). Who knows if they will ever be removed. The key thing, however, is that you should stop using deprecated features, or at least schedule development time to remove them, so that when/if they are removed, you're ready.

Comment: This feature has been deprecated for at least 15 years now (possibly longer, I can't check the docs back that far). It may be removed in any future release if MS deems this a good idea to simplify the engine's internal logic (for example, to make implementing another feature easier) or it may continue to hang around for another 15 years -- anyone's guess. For limiting resource use, consider Resource Governor. For specifically targeting individual queries, use `TOP` and common table expressions.

Comment: ["We strive not to remove a deprecated feature from future releases to make upgrades easier. However, under rare situations, we may choose to permanently discontinue (remove) the feature from SQL Server if it limits future innovations."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Charlieface I wish to use it in a feature that executes SQL queries strings. These queries can have multiple SELECT's in them and can also have transaction logics such as IF (SOMETHING) SELECT X ELSE SELECT Y. So I would like to have a systematic way of limiting the return without needing to check every SELECT inside the query string...